# make google talk use the correct alsa sound device for input

Tags: alsa

I'm trying to make the Google Talk plugin accept sound. In other programs (e.g. Skype, Audacity) I did this by selecting the device for my sound input, hw:0.2 (see screenshots). Google Talk does not give me that option, shows instead only output devices and a default device.

I tried to further configure the default capture device, but that did not help. Perhaps I did it the wrong way? Or maybe there is a way to create a device that Google Talk will pick up and allow me to select it?

[image: selected input in audacity]
[image: selected input in skype]
[image: devices in Google Talk are very different]

`.asoundrc`

```
pcm.!default {
type hw
card 0
}

ctl.!default {
type hw
card 0
}

# try to help Google Talk
pcm.!default {
         type asym
         capture.pcm {
                 type plug
                 slave.pcm "hw:0,2"
         } 
} 
# end test for Google Talk

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type asym
        playback.pcm "dmix:SB"
        capture.pcm "dsnoop:SB"
    }
}

# Make OSS apps default to using dmix plugin too
pcm.dsp0 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "dmix"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only have a single `pcm.!default` entry in your asoundrc (you seem to have 3! - which one is google talk to choose?)

anyhow, you should be able to make a virtual device (as configured in `~/.asoundrc`) appear in device listings by adding a *description-hint*:

```
     # try to help Google Talk
     pcm.googletalk {
       type asym
       capture.pcm {
             type plug
             slave.pcm "hw:0,2"
       }
       hint {
          description "special device so gtalk can use it"
       }
     }
```

Comment: I'm very grateful for the info on how to make a virtual device. I tested it in Skype, and it works nicely (and it, or my decluttered .asoundrc fixed a distortion that Skype had).  However, Google Talk still doesn't show sound, so I'm guessing it's a bug in the Google Talk plugin. Thanks!